# Validate unique array values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, validation, unique

My Transaction model generates an array of unique ticket numbers based on quantity (an integer column) with the following controller logic:

```
@transaction.quantity.times.uniq { @transaction.ticket_numbers << rand(100000..999999) }
```

However, this only ensures that the numbers WITHIN the array are unique.

I need a database validation that checks ALL Transaction.ticket_numbers arrays to ensure that every value (ticket number) is unique across ALL arrays.

Here is my Transaction table within schema.rb:

```
  create_table "transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "payee"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.decimal "debt", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.string "email"
    t.string "ministry"
    t.integer "status"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "ticket_numbers", default: [], array: true
  end
```

Transaction model from transaction.rb:

```
require 'csv'

class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :email, :format => { :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/, :on => [:create, :update] }
  validates :payee, presence: true
  validates :quantity, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }
  validates :debt, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{payee email ministry quantity debt status ticket_numbers}
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes
      all.each do |transaction|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| transaction.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Transaction controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_transaction, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
    if @transaction.save
      @transaction.quantity.times.uniq { @transaction.ticket_numbers << rand(100000..999999) }
    end
    @user = @transaction.user
    @transactions = @user.transactions
    respond_to do |format|
      if @transaction.save && @transaction.status == 1
        UserMailer.payment_confirmation(@transaction).deliver_later
        format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice:'Transaction added & ticket sent' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      elsif @transaction.save && @transaction.status != 1
        format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice:'Transaction added' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render 'users/show' }
        format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    update_ticket_numbers
    respond_to do |format|
      if @transaction.update_attributes(transaction_params) && @transaction.status == 1
        UserMailer.payment_confirmation(@transaction).deliver_later
        format.html { redirect_to user_url(current_user), notice: 'Transaction info updated & confirmation email sent to payee' }
        format.json { render json: current_user, status: :created, location: current_user }
      elsif @transaction.update_attributes(transaction_params) && @transaction.status != 1
        format.html { redirect_to user_url(current_user), notice: 'Transaction info updated' }
        format.json { render json: current_user, status: :created, location: current_user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @transaction.destroy
    redirect_to user_url(current_user), notice: 'Transaction deleted'
  end

  private

  def load_transaction
    @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])
  end

  def transaction_params
    params.require(:transaction).permit(:payee, :email, :ministry, :debt,
    :quantity, :status, :user_id, :ticket_numbers)
  end

  def update_ticket_numbers
    if @transaction.update_attributes(transaction_params)
      if @transaction.ticket_numbers.length < @transaction.quantity
        i = @transaction.quantity - @transaction.ticket_numbers.length
        i.times.uniq { @transaction.ticket_numbers << rand(100000..999999) }
      elsif @transaction.ticket_numbers.length > @transaction.quantity
        i = @transaction.ticket_numbers.length - @transaction.quantity
        i.times { @transaction.ticket_numbers.pop }
      end
    end
  end
```

end

Comment: Would it be easier to work with ticket numbers if they were in their own separate model/table instead of an array?

Comment: I can see what you're getting at, but if I use a separate model it would be purely for generating ticket numbers which can be added & removed when Transaction.quantity is edited. I also use ActionMailer to automate emails when transactions are marked complete on the form.  Wouldn't a ticket number model be excessive for this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert but can't you try intersections of all the arrays and check if the intersection is empty to find uniqueness?

Comment: @D_Cheeles I think Brad's suggestion will ultimately be _less_ excessive than the path you are currently on. Databases are good at unique constraints. You should take advantage of that if you can.

Comment: @DCheeles can you edit your question to explain your Transaction model a little more and what the ticket numbers are in relation to a Transaction? Does a Transaction have many ticket_numbers, where are the ticket numbers being stored (column named ticket_number?) and how (an array column, json column, text column?). I have the feeling that many people (myself included) are looking at your question and thinking you need a Ticket model, so more explanation would be helpful as to why you don't need this.

Comment: @DRSE Thanks for the responses! I've updated my question with the table, model & controller files. I'm open to creating a Ticket model if that is the most efficient way of saving unique ticket numbers into my db, I just thought that having all of the logic done within one model would be the fastest. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DCheeles, there's a joke that goes "Boss, I wrote a program that does the wrong thing but does it really fast". Make it right first, worry about performance later when it becomes an issue. Like other have said, I think you should create a separate model for the `Ticket` and implement the constraint with a unique index.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom ticket number validation to your model.  You can read more about them [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)

```rb
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  validate :ticket_number_uniqueness

  def ticket_number_uniqueness
    # First check all new ticket numbers are unique from each other
    errors.add(:ticket_number, "is not unique") unless ticket_numbers == ticket_numbers.uniq
    
    # Next check against other ticket numbers
    ticket_numbers.each do |ticket|
      if ::Transaction.where("ticket_numbers @> '{?}'", ticket).exists?
        errors.add(:ticket_number, "is not unique")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note: this is taking advantage of Postgres contains array method @>.  You can learn more about array methods [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-array.html)

Comment: This looks like this should work without a separate Ticket model. One thing I would change is the ticket_numbers == ticket_numbers.uniq comparison. There is no guarantee that the order will be consistent against the original after the call to uniq. Sorting should be applied or alternatively a set comparison should be made instead.

Comment: What makes you think the order isn't guaranteed?  https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/uniq. I would suggest a simple length comparison `ticket_numbers.size == ticket_numbers.uniq.size` as an alternative, which may give a performance improvement as well, but wanted to keep things simple in my answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the order is *not* guaranteed. The documentation there says nothing about the order of the returned array. Practically speaking, you're probably right though.

Comment: why do you use double colon operator before `Transaction` model?

Comment: Habit ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.  It's not necessary, but it is explicit.